# Linux: How to measure memory usage for a thread within process?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading

I want to measure memory usage for each thread within process. Is it possible? I'm trying to figure out which thread leaks memory.

Edit 1.
The pmap for leaking process shows ~600 allocation by [ anon ]

```
...
63b00000    772K rw---    [ anon ]
63bc1000    252K -----    [ anon ]
63c00000    772K rw---    [ anon ]
63cc1000    252K -----    [ anon ]
63d00000    772K rw---    [ anon ]
...
```

Advice on what to do next?

Edit 2. 
Only virtual memory is leaking e.g. physical memory usage is stable.

Comment: What does that mean ? How do you link some part of the memory to a given thread ?

Comment: As no thread really has "ownership" of memory beyond what is established by convention in the source code, I would think this is impossible.  However, I'm interested to see if anyone has a partial solution.

Comment: Are you familiar with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?

Comment: Threads uses new() or malloc(), I believe only way to link memory and thread is to override new() operator and store memory usage per thread ID in some kind of global table.

Comment: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is your friend.

Comment: I know valgrind, but this is customer RT device. I can not use valgrind on it.

Comment: What is a "Customer RT device"? Seems curious that you can write code to target it but cannot use debugging tools upon it!

Comment: @Rook, probably debug libs are not provided

Comment: @Rook, When code is already loaded to target device I have strictly limited access to it. (telecom Real-time Device running Montavista Linux). Only simple Linux commands are allowed. I`m not able to reproduce the issue in lab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No this isn't possible, because memory isn't attached to a thread but to the process. There is no link between a thread and some part of the memory.

What you seem to need is a profiler, which would point to the allocation points. One of them (didn't use it in the last decade) is [Rational Purify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Purify).

Answer (score 2):

You generally can't identify the memory usage of a thread because memory ownership can freely move between threads. The kernel mapping tables will show you the usage of the process as a whole, i.e. the memory allocated for all threads.

Thread programming is *hard*. Unless you really need to freely share pointers and memory between threads - which is a fairly nasty code smell - it will probably be easier to debug if you rework your program as a flock of processes that communicate over IPC, which will also force you to consider which state needs to be shared. As a bonus, if the leaky process turns out to be a relatively short-lived one, the memory is returned to the system on `exit()` without you having to locate and patch the leak.

Comment: Generally I agree, but in my case system is working already. The only thing I can do is prepare a patch to detect a source of leak. I'm trying to find out, how should look like the contents of the patch.